# Product Filter not working when I change language in Magento

Tags: magento, filter, product

My product filter is not working when I change language from English to Myanmar. In English language it works just fine and shows filtered products. When I change the language the values of the attribute are translated but filter does not work at all. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I also want to know how i can do that.....